# Superscript "L" Symbol Sprinkled in text in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, random, symbols

I'm working on a site that is very text heavy and the site looks fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. But when I test it in Internet Explorer it has random scattered superscript "L" Symbols on the text. I looked back to the code to see if there was anything extra written in it causing the L but there was nothing. The main problem is on the homepage.

Here's the site:
http://emilymagnuson.com/mynews2/index.html

And you have to look at it in IE to see the problem.

Comment: Try to change the char-set IE uses for display. If that fixes the issue something is causing IE to not recognize it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the HTML of your website, you have extraneous characters in your text where the Ls are appearing.  Your HTML specifies UTF-8.  You need to be certain that your editor is saving your text in UTF-8 and not in something else.  Deleting those extra characters should clear the problem.  I was using Notepad++ as my editor, and they showed up clearly.  I saw the Ls in Opera so it is not just an IE problem.

Comment: I'm working on a Mac so I downloaded Text Wrangler. I copy, pasted the code from the browser to Text Wrangler, but the extraeous characters did not show up. Is there a different way to see the characters or up load the code to Text Wrangler?

Comment: I also downloaded Opera and viewed the code of the page through Opera and still didn't see the Extraneous Characters. Could you show me what they look like? Thank you!

Comment: In Opera I get "Kim Jung III New Leader of North Korea"  That doesn't show the extra character, but notice that there are two spaces between III and New.  The second space is the extra character.  Looking closely at it, it isn't actually a space but a line drawing character.  Looking at it in hex I get:

Comment: Whoops, I posted too early.  Here's the rest.  Looking at it in hex I get: `2003` for the two spaces, which is a normal space, `20` followed by ETX, `03`.  For some reason the ETX is displaying as Unicode U+2514 (&#9492;) or similar.  It is certainly not valid UTF-8, which is what the browser is expecting.

Comment: What I got from your comments was that there was extra spaces, and in the second space lied the problem. So I went through the code and deleted the second space and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer sometimes renders text differently than other browsers. My suggestion is to create a separate stylesheet specifically for IE.  In that stylesheet only allow it to use serif fonts in the paragraph tags like this:

Enter this on the main CSS

```
<![if !IE]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
<![endif]>
```

In the not-ie-css:

```
p {
 font-family: serif;
 }
```