# Strange symbols popping up on IE8 but no other browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

[image]

I'm having a very strange problem with IE8 where the paragraph text is cropping up strange angular symbols seemingly at random. Here is a sample of the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="html">
 <head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="generator" content="7.1.329.244"/>
  <title>Friends of Hartpury School Promises Auction 2014</title>
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site_global.css?4151054444"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master_a-master.css?428943956"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css?308194328" id="pagesheet"/>
  <!-- Other scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   document.documentElement.className += ' js';
</script>
   </head>
 <body>

  <div class="clearfix" id="page"><!-- column -->
   <div class="position_content" id="page_position_content">
    <div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu196"><!-- group -->
     <div class="browser_width grpelem" id="u196"><!-- group -->
      <div class="clearfix" id="u196_align_to_page">
       <div class="clip_frame grpelem" id="u203"><!-- image -->
        <img class="block" id="u203_img" src="images/friends-of.png" alt="" width="126" height="122"/>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="clip_frame grpelem" id="u197"><!-- image -->
      <img class="block" id="u197_img" src="images/banners.png" alt="" width="214" height="64"/>
     </div>
     <div class="clip_frame grpelem" id="u199"><!-- image -->
      <img class="block" id="u199_img" src="images/banners.png" alt="" width="214" height="64"/>
     </div>
     <div class="clip_frame grpelem" id="u277"><!-- image -->
      <img class="block" id="u277_img" src="images/header.png" alt="" width="604" height="248"/>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u276-11"><!-- content -->
     <p><a class="nonblock" href="index.html">THE AUCTION</a>&nbsp;| <a class="nonblock" href="tickets.html">TICKETS</a>&nbsp;| <a class="nonblock" href="rules---submit-bid.html">RULES &amp; SUBMIT BID</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="rounded-corners clearfix colelem" id="u375"><!-- group -->
     <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u376-8"><!-- content -->
      <p id="u376-2">Welcome to our Promises Auction website where you can see the fabulous promises that have been donated by friends, family, local and national businesses to support our school.</p>
      <p id="u376-4">A huge thank you to all our sponsors!</p>
      <p id="u376-6">All funds raised will go towards our Hartpury IT 21st Century appeal. In this age of technology our server is creaking, our few laptops are old and slow and all four classes in school have access to just one central printer. We need to raise £10,000 over the school year to help purchase a new server, new laptops, upgraded interactive whiteboards and printers for each classroom. If possible we would also like to provide e&#45;readers too.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u526"><!-- group -->
     <div class="pointer_cursor rounded-corners clearfix grpelem" id="u517"><!-- group -->
      <a class="block" href="http://#"></a>
      <a class="nonblock nontext clearfix grpelem" id="u520-4" href="http://#"><!-- content --><p>PROMISES SO FAR</p></a>
      <a class="nonblock nontext clip_frame grpelem" id="u521" href="http://#"><!-- image --><img class="block" id="u521_img" src="images/forward.png" alt="" width="38" height="38"/></a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu527"><!-- group -->
     <div class="rounded-corners clearfix grpelem" id="u527"><!-- group -->
      <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u533-11"><!-- content -->
       <p id="u533-2">How to donate</p>
       <p class="ts-Default-Link-Style--copy" id="u533-7">If our catalogue inspires you to donate a promise, please use this <a class="nonblock" href="rules---submit-bid.html"><span id="u533-4">donor form</span></a>&nbsp;and someone from the auction team will contact you.</p>
       <p id="u533-9">Thank you so much for your support.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="rounded-corners clearfix grpelem" id="u528"><!-- group -->
      <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u529-17"><!-- content -->
       <p id="u529-2">What if I can’t make the Auction?</p>
       <p id="u529-4">Hopefully the catalogue will tempt you to come along to the Auction on 29th can’t make it then advance bids can be submitted by:</p>
       <p class="Paragraph-Style" id="u529-8">Submitting an <a class="nonblock" href="rules---submit-bid.html"><span id="u529-6">on&#45;line bid</span></a></p>
       <p class="Paragraph-Style" id="u529-13">Completing <a class="nonblock" href="http://www.hartpuryauction.co.uk/formdownload/PreAuctionBidForm.doc"><span id="u529-10">this pre&#45;auction bid form</span></a>&nbsp;and placing it in a &nbsp; sealed envelope addressed to FOHS Promises Auction c/o the school office.</p>
       <p id="u529-15">Please read our very simple rules before submitting your bid.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="rounded-corners grpelem" id="u872"><!-- simple frame --></div>
     <div class="rounded-corners grpelem" id="u873"><!-- simple frame --></div>
    </div>
    <div class="verticalspacer"></div>
    <div class="browser_width colelem" id="u356"><!-- column -->
     <div class="clearfix" id="u356_align_to_page">
      <div class="position_content" id="u356_position_content">
       <div class="clip_frame colelem" id="u362"><!-- image -->
        <img class="block" id="u362_img" src="images/footer-banner.png" alt="" width="604" height="125"/>
       </div>
       <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u368-4"><!-- content -->
        <p>Suas appareat pro eu. Te sea liber senserit maluisset, diam moderatius ea quo. Qui at purto docendi placerat, pertinax efficiendi mea ei. Adhuc fugit eloquentiam ut usu.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- JS includes -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   if (document.location.protocol != 'https:') document.write('\x3Cscript src="http://musecdn.businesscatalyst.com/scripts/4.0/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">\x3C/script>');
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   window.jQuery || document.write('\x3Cscript src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">\x3C/script>');
</script>
  <script src="scripts/museutils.js?117816282" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.tobrowserwidth.js?152985095" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.watch.js?4199601726" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Other scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() { try {
Muse.Utils.transformMarkupToFixBrowserProblemsPreInit();/* body */
$('.browser_width').toBrowserWidth();/* browser width elements */
Muse.Utils.prepHyperlinks(true);/* body */
Muse.Utils.fullPage('#page');/* 100% height page */
Muse.Utils.showWidgetsWhenReady();/* body */
Muse.Utils.transformMarkupToFixBrowserProblems();/* body */
} catch(e) { Muse.Assert.fail('Error calling selector function:' + e); }});
</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean the symbol that looks like a little `L`? Well that’s in your actual source code that you posted here … if you don’t want those characters, then why do you put them in there …?

Comment: I'm sorry I cant see those in the source code, am I just being blind? And why do the show up in IE8 but not in any other browser?

Comment: The first one is right here, `<p id="u376-2">Welcome to our Promises Auction website where` before the word `where`. And if I copy&paste your HTML and feed it to the HTML validator, it says those are invalid UTF-8 code sequences (which is why I can post the actual character here in comments as well, although I see them in your source code – and which is most likely why other browsers don’t display them). Use a HEX editor or something to look which character that actually is at that position in your source code.

Comment: I think you have copied the text from a word processor. from where these symbols may occur. Yes the symbols are shown in code, you can remove it. use sublime text editor to view it. that symbols is marked as ETX

Comment: possible duplicate of [Superscript "L" Symbol Sprinkled in text in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092218/superscript-l-symbol-sprinkled-in-text-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

If you copy your code and paste it into another editor (I'm using Notepad++), you will see the weird symbols in your text.

You will need to go back and erase these characters and paste it back into your website.  And then when inserting new content into your site, you need to make sure the text is written in/or saved as charset=UTF-8, which is what your site specifies.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a similar report in an Adobe post.

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1073776

It wasn't really 'solved' but you may try deleting characters that seem like spaces and putting them back in. There could be characters that appear to be spaces to your editor (and other browsers) that are actually a different char.