# Strange characters showing up in paragraphs

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer

One of my client's websites started randomly showing these strange little "L" characters in random areas of paragraphs. This is happening for her in Chrome and in IE. When I check it, however, I don't see them at all and everything looks fine. Anyone know why this would be happening? I've included a photo she sent me.

The site is www.shortandsuitebnb.com

[See photo of issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80WPV.jpg)

Comment: On my browser(chrome), on the `hosts` page, there is a broken character in the text, '', which is ASCII `ETX`, hex `0x03`.

Comment: See also this similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092218/superscript-l-symbol-sprinkled-in-text-in-internet-explorer I think whatever software you are using to create the source for the website is not saving the files correctly, or something along those lines. Double check your HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

I can see it too - on my browser(Chrome), on the hosts page, there is a broken character in the text, '', which is ASCII `ETX`, hex `0x03`. It's present in the network tab too, so it is not a local issue.

Are you using Photoshop? From what I see online, people have issues copying text from it introducing control characters like this.

https://codeandsend.com/blog/email-photoshop-and-invisible-characters/

> Now when SHIFT+ENTER is clicked, behind the scenes, Photoshop adds an
>   invisible character called ETX into the text. If the text is copied
>   into other software, ETX is retained and can cause trouble.

https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/22859-invalid-character-server-stack-error#comment-113512

> I had this issue in 6.05 - It was a copying/pasting from Photoshop
>   issue as well.  I just copied the text into sublimetext. It showed up
>   the ETX chracter that caused the issue. Deleted it and pasted
>   back...and it works.

Try pasting the text into an editor like Sublime Text which shows the control characters, delete them, and then paste them into Wordpress or whatever you are using for the site.